# why am I getting an error saying that "the Transaction has been reverted and that the function should be payable.." on a regular function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

ragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract B {
mapping(uint => uint) map;

```
function init(uint k, uint v) public {
    map[k] -= v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its beacuse `map[k] -= v` is doing this : `0-v`, you can not make `uint` negative

use `init function` after adding some value to `map[k]` where `v` should be smaller then `map[k]`.

Try this code. (first ADD map[k]).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract B { 
    mapping(uint => uint) map;
    function add(uint k, uint v) public {
        map[k]+=v;
    }
    function init(uint k, uint v) public {
        map[k] -= v;
    }
    function get(uint k) public view returns(uint){
        return map[k];
    }
}
```